# Choropleth map layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, vector, vector-layer, choropleth

I tried to mimic the solution from [Creating choropleth map using OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276918/creating-choropleth-map-using-openlayers). My implementation is as follows:

```
    const temperatureSource = new VectorSource({
    features: tempData
      .filter((_, index) => index % 10 === 0) // only keep every 10th value
      .map((point) => {
        {
          return new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([point.Long, point.Lat])),
            temperature: point.t,
          });
        }
      }),
  });

    const map = new Map({
    target: mapRef.current,
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM(),
      }),
      new Vector({
        source: temperatureSource, 
        // temperatureSource is a VectorSource which works well with other styles.
        style: function () {
          return new Style({
            fill: new Fill({
              color: [255, 255, 0, 0.5],
            }),
            // semi-transparent red
          });
        },
      }),
    ],
    view: new View({
      center: fromLonLat([9, 53]),
      zoom: 5,
    }),
  });
```

I returned just static value in style (just for testing purpose), I can't see anything on my output except for base map, but I was aiming to render a map as below

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: See styling of vector layer in this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html. What is missing in your code above is structure (properties) of your source `temperatureSource`.

Comment: do you mean something like this?
   format: new GeoJSON()

Comment: I didn't mean there is missing something in the code, missing is part of the code that creates `temperatureSource` and the structure of the data used for the source.

Comment: Don't put code and additional info in comments, rather [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/459178/edit) the question and put it there.

Comment: I updated the code above, if it is of any help.

Comment: You cannot create choropleth map with point data, it has to be polygons so that you can then color/style them on the basis of data/properties attached to them.